# I know not if I ~

Tags: grammar, sentence, sentence-patterns, syntactic-analysis

I know not if I will ~

What does it mean?
What is I know not if I ~?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is much too simple, and belongs on English Language Learners if anywhere.

Comment: *Fair Phyllis I saw sitting all alone /
Feeding her flock near to the mountain side. /
**The shepherds knew not, /
they knew not whither she was gone,** /
But after her lover Amyntas hied, /
Up and down he wandered /
whilst she was missing; /
When he found her, /
O then they fell a-kissing.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*I know not ~*" is an alternative form of "*I don't know ~*". Thus, "I know not if I will embrace those tomorrows" is simply "I don't know if I will embrace those tomorrows".

Another sentence with a similar structure (but with much simpler subject matter):

> I don't know if I will eat the cake nor if I will enjoy the cake, yet the chocolate frosting looks delicious.